# Why is my busy page not working?

Tags: wpf, xaml, binding

I'm trying to develop a busy Window as said  [here](http://weblogs.asp.net/psteele/wpf-simple-busy-overlay) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4505644/how-to-display-a-busy-message-over-a-wpf-screen?answertab=active#tab-top). I want a grid to be visible whenver  I need it to be visible, for example while I'm doing a long task.

I did this til now:

**The XAML:**

```
<Window x:Class="LoadingWindow2.MainWindow"
   xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:loadingWindow2="clr-namespace:LoadingWindow2"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Window.Resources>
    <loadingWindow2:BoolToVisibilityConverter x:Key="boolConverter"/>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <Label HorizontalAlignment="Right">
        <Hyperlink Command="{Binding Path=DoSomething}">Do Something</Hyperlink>
    </Label>
    <Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1" Background="#80000000" Visibility="{Binding IsBusy, Converter={StaticResource boolConverter}}" Grid.RowSpan="3">
        <Grid>
            <TextBlock Margin="0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Please Wait..." HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontSize="24" FontWeight="Bold" Foreground="#7EFFFFFF"/>
        </Grid>
    </Border>
</Grid>
```

**My .cs:**

**The BusyViewModel.cs:**

```
public class BusyViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private ICommand doSomethingCommand;

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public bool IsBusy { get; set; }

    public ICommand DoSomething
    {
        get { return doSomethingCommand ?? (doSomethingCommand = new DelegateCommand(LongRunningTask)); }
    }

    private void LongRunningTask()
    {
        var task = new Task(ComputeResults);
        task.Start();
    }

    private void ComputeResults()
    {
        this.IsBusy = true;
        Thread.Sleep(5000);
        this.IsBusy = false;
    }
}
```

**The DelegateCommand.cs:**

```
public class DelegateCommand : ICommand
{
    private readonly Action executeMethod;
    private readonly Func<bool> canExecuteMethod;

    public DelegateCommand(Action executeMethod)
        : this(executeMethod, () => true)
    {
    }

    public DelegateCommand(Action executeMethod, Func<bool> canExecuteMethod)
    {
        if (executeMethod == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("executeMethod");
        if (canExecuteMethod == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("canExecuteMethod");

        this.executeMethod = executeMethod;
        this.canExecuteMethod = canExecuteMethod;
    }

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
    {
        add { CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value; }
        remove { CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value; }
    }

    public bool CanExecute(object stupid)
    {
        return CanExecute();
    }

    public bool CanExecute()
    {
        return canExecuteMethod();
    }

    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        Execute();
    }

    public void Execute()
    {
        executeMethod();
    }

    public void OnCanExecuteChanged()
    {
        CommandManager.InvalidateRequerySuggested();
    }
}
```

**MainWindow.xaml.cs:**

```
 public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = new BusyViewModel();
    }
```

I downloaded the source code from the first link I copied, and the `busy Grid` is showing. But in my case... is NOT!!! What I'm doing wrong here?

**EDIT:** I deleted the `Converter` as suggested. But it's not working yet... I add my `MainWindow.xaml.cs"

The whole source: [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/fq6jmx607y0bn11/LoadingWindow.zip)

Comment: Why not just use the code you downloaded and is working?

Comment: I have to insert this code in a big project. And if it doesn't work on a little project... why should work in the big one? And... the big question: Why is not working if it's the same?

Comment: Why not use the code that is working?

Comment: -1  The dropbox link to your source is NOT the same as what you posted.  The posted code does not have the error.

Comment: @Blam as I said in my comments with MAVBT's solution, I'm using HIS code, not mine anymore. But using that code I had problems anyway because, as MAVBT said, I was not sending the OnPropertyChanged event. Same code with that event, is working. But I uploaded what MAVBT was suggesting.

Comment: No were not using his code.  His code did not have that error.  And the code you posted does not have that error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a converter available from WPF already, the "booleanToVisibilityConverter" that does the job.

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.windows.controls.booleantovisibilityconverter%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Edit your xaml like this:

```
<Window x:Class="LoadingWindow2.MainWindow"
   xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
   xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
   xmlns:loadingWindow2="clr-namespace:LoadingWindow2"
   Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.Resources>    
        <BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="boolConverter"/>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid x:Name="ROOT">
        <Label HorizontalAlignment="Right">
            <Hyperlink Command="{Binding Path=DoSomething}">Do Something</Hyperlink>
   </Label>
   <Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1" Background="#80000000" Visibility="{Binding Path=IsBusy, Converter={StaticResource boolConverter}}" Grid.RowSpan="3">
       <Grid>
           <TextBlock Margin="0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Please Wait..." 
            horizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontSize="24" FontWeight="Bold" Foreground="#7EFFFFFF"/>
   </Border>
</Grid>
```

---

**EDIT:** Implementation of BusyViewMOdel

```
public class BusyViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
private ICommand doSomethingCommand;

public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

private bool _isBusy = false;
public bool IsBusy 
{
    get { return _isBusy; }
    set
    {
       _isBusy = value;
       OnPropertyChanged("IsBusy");
    }
}

// Create the OnPropertyChanged method to raise the event
  protected void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
  {
      PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
      if (handler != null)
      {
          handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
      }
  }


public ICommand DoSomething
{
    get { return doSomethingCommand ?? (doSomethingCommand = new DelegateCommand(LongRunningTask)); }
}

private void LongRunningTask()
{
    var task = new Task(ComputeResults);
    task.Start();
}

private void ComputeResults()
{
    this.IsBusy = true;
    Thread.Sleep(5000);
    this.IsBusy = false;
}
}
```

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ms743695%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

---

**EDIT:** Try to set the data context on the root grid by giving the grid a name and instead of `this.DataContext = ...` in `public MainWindow() ...`do `ROOT.DataContext = ...`. See updated xaml!

---

**EDIT:** Got it working. See this code of class BusyViewModel.

```
    private void LongRunningTask()
    {
        var task = new Task(ComputeResults);
        task.Start();
    }

    private void ComputeResults()
    {
        this.IsBusy = true; // you did _isBusy = true. but to invoke OnPropertyChanged you need to use the setter, thus IsBusy! Works now even if set in the worker thread. Put it back to ComputeResults!
        Thread.Sleep(5000);
        this.IsBusy = false;
    }
```

Comment: Still not working  with that... Do you think is because of the `Converter`?

Comment: Ah i think the problem resides somewhere else. Could you please show the code behindo f the mainwindow?

Comment: I think that your implementation of the BusyViewModel is not correct. Where to you implement the notification of property changed. See the answer

Comment: See the updated xaml. ( x:name=ROOT and the update in the converter binding ). The DelegateCommand is not of interest for the visibility concerns.

Comment: I tried that before, now is always visible... -_- And never reports any change.

Comment: Did what you mentioned in your edit... This is exhausting and depressing... Still not working!

Comment: Ah... I think this is also affected by a threading issue. Put `this.IsBusy = true;` before `task.Start();` to see if the Busy Page now activates! If yes then the solution is to put the value assignment of this.IsBusy = true/false; into the main thread, i.e. before starting the task and than in a mainthread method after the task has finished! DataBinding can be exhausting!

Comment: Not working... I'm not understanding anything right now... I understand Bindings, but I think not more from today!

Comment: If you don't mind, provide the workspace and I'm gonna work on it till its fixed because I cannot see any errors anymore.